# Почему пишется одна буква Н в кратких прилагательных на -енен?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные

К примеру, *безнравственный* — полная форма, *безнравственен* — краткая, однако в той же краткой форме, но в ж.р. пишется *безнравственна*. Согласно правилу правописания кр. форм прилагательных, пишем столько букв *н*, сколько в полной. Несмотря на это, в таких словах, как безнравственен, бездейственен, мужественен и т.п., мы пишем одну. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Безнрав/ственн/ый — безнрав/ственн/а, безнрав/ствен(е)н.**

В форме м. рода нулевое окончание и беглая гласная Е в суффиксе.

**При образовании кратких форм от ряда прилагательных могут отмечаться следующие особенности:**

- в прилагательных с суффиксами –енн- (-а(нн-) – в формах мужского рода происходит усечение конечного суффиксального –н: дружественный – дружествен, болезненный – болезнен, образованный – образован;

https://studopedia.ru/2_33377_lektsiya--.html

Answer (score 1):

Разве вы не видите двух Н? Смотрите: безнравствеНеН. Часто это конечное "ен" отбрасывается: воспитанный - воспитан и т.п. А слова "бездейственен" (хоть с "ен", хоть без него) и вовсе нет.